# Array Override itself in Node. And giving me different output

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the Problem in this code?

```
let list = ['*','*'];
let newList=[]; 
newList.push(list);

for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    if (i==0) list[i] = 'A';
    newList.push(list);
    if (i==1) list[i] = 'B';
    newList.push(list);
}
console.log(newList)
```

The output should be like -> `[['*','*'],['A','*'],['A','B']]`

But I got the following output. ->

```
`[ [ 'A', 'B' ],
  [ 'A', 'B' ],
  [ 'A', 'B' ],
  [ 'A', 'B' ],
  [ 'A', 'B' ] ]`
```

Can please explain to me, Why this output appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are objects in JavaScript, and `list` holds a reference to an array. `newList` contains references to same `list` object, `newList[0] === newList[1]`. Once `list` is modified, it will appear the same way everywhere the reference to it is used.

A new array should be created on each iteration:

```
let list = ['*','*'];
let newList=[]; 
newList.push(list);

for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    list = [...list];

    if (i==0) list[i] = 'A';
    if (i==1) list[i] = 'B';
    newList.push(list);
}
```

Comment: Plus the `newList.push` should be executed inside the `if` block to get the expected result `[['*','*'],['A','*'],['A','B']]`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Seems like there's unnecessary `newList.push(list)`.